# appendix package does not support the option "header" in the subappendices environment -- workaround?

Tags: header-footer, appendices

Basically what the title says. Is there a way to automatically have "Appendix A -- Title" in the page header instead of "A -- Title" when using the subappendices environment of the appendix package? I learned from the package documentation that this is not supported, but I need to use the subappendices environment, because I have appendices at the end of every chapter.

Comment: We have a strange obsession on `MWE` -- please provide a compilable document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible way -- use `\AtBeginEnvironment` do add some code that redefines `\sectionmark` according to the needs.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
 \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
   \if@twoside
   \markboth{\appendixname\ \Alph{section}\ -- #1}{}
   \else
   \markright{\appendixname\ \Alph{section}\ --  #1}{}
   \fi
 }
}
\makeatother



\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\blindtext[5]

\begin{subappendices}
  \section{Foo}
\blindtext[5]

  \section{Another Foo}
\blindtext[5]
\end{subappendices}

\chapter{Another Chapter}

\blindtext[5]

\begin{subappendices}
  \section{Yet another foo}
\blindtext[5]
\end{subappendices}



\end{document}
```